# Ping reply not getting to LAN machines but getting in Linux router Gateway,Internet not working on client

Tags: linux, centos, gateway

I have configured Centos 6.2 as Gateway machine.its having two interfaces

eth0 with ip address that provided by isp 116.x.x.x(Static) and eth1 with ip address 192.168.0.1(no,dns,no dhcp configured yet just ip-forwarding is enabled in router box).

**Client machine is configured as:**

```
ip address 192.168.0.5 and gateway 192.168.0.1
```

After i reboot centos,iptables rules are not all gone.

**STEPS FOLLOWED**

Router machine:two interfaces eth0:116.X.X.X(static ip) eth1:192.168.0.1

> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
>
> iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT

Save the iptable rules in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Selinix is disabled.

changes done on /etc/sysctl.conf

> sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

But still when system reboot everything gone.

Comment: Do you enable ip forward in Centos server?

Comment: yes i did,everything is going fine before restart,but after restart no connectivity to internet from client side

Comment: I would expect that the nic connected to "the modem" (eth1) would be the internet facing IP?

Comment: yes eth1 is internet facing ip

Comment: Couple of things. 1. Double check you ip_forward is still enable `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` 2. What does your routing table look like `route -n` 3. You have under you steps followed eth1 is set to 192.168.0.3, is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you enabled ip forwarding, did you set it in sysctl.conf so that it is pervasive across reboots?

Setting it via sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1   or  echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward is only good for the current runtime and it is reset to the default or whatever is in /etc/sysctl.conf at boot time.

Also make sure that your iptables rules are getting saved in /etc/sysconfig/iptables

Comment: i did everything as described by you,but still the result is same

Comment: At this point I would start adding logging rules into iptables `-j LOG --log-prefix <some text indicating which table>` and running `tcpdump -ni eth0` and `tcpdump -ni eth1` on the router and see what is happening to the packets.

Comment: can elaborate it more,plz.....i configured and install centos and other distro many times,never face such issue,don't know why this time i am facing it.....if possible can you plz give me all steps that has perform while installing and configuring centos as a internet gateway(permanent settingings so that it won't go after restart)...Please its important for me to do it as soon as possible